# How to make background videos that has large aspect ratios to fit window screen without getting cropped?

Tags: html, css

I am in the midst of figuring out if there are other methods/techniques on how you can fit a background video that has large aspect ratios to be seen in full on landing page without getting cropped. Right now, the only solution i have found was to add `object-fit:cover` to the video element. It did the trick. However, its not compatible to Internet explorer. The true aspect ratio of the video I'm using is 3840X2160. I already tried adding width and height property in viewport to the parent element but it didn't work.

Below is my current code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="v-header container">
    <div class="fullscreen-video-wrap"> 
        <video src="video1.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CURRENT CSS**

```
.fullscreen-video-wrap video{

position: absolute;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index:-1;

}
```

**PREVIOUS CSS CODE WITH SOLUTION** with `object-fit:cover`

```
.fullscreen-video-wrap video{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left: 0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index: -1;
object-fit: cover;          
}
```

Comment: have you tried max-width and height instead of min?  The only browser object fit is not compatible with is ie and you should be able to get a polyfill for it

Comment: yes i did try those but was unable to get what i wanted as i got a white spaces/spaces around  the video when resizing to smaller screens.

Comment: but if the aspect ratio of the screen doesn't match the video aspect ratio then I don't think it will fill the screen

Comment: for smaller videos you can stretch them, idk what else to do if video is supposed to be larger than the native resolution of your screen monitor. is there a fix for the object-fit cover to work in ie?

Answer (score 1):

Consider trying to use CSS vw (view width) and/or vh (view height). Using these units like I did below, it shouldn't get cropped (although they may have to scroll to see the full height, with it set to auto). I tested your code with an image instead of a video because I don't have a video with that resolution on hand.

```
.fullscreen-video-wrap video{
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index:-1;
}

.fullscreen-video{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Here's the codepen where I tried it out, so you can play around with the idea:https://codepen.io/gemiller/pen/PXqpYQ . You can also learn more about vh/vw here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: this works!one problem though on my code. i had container with `max-width` and this was messing up your solution. i removed it and everything went fine.